# Regular Expression to check a number with first three characters are alphabets not working

Tags: javascript, regex

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#mystring").keyup(function(){
            var name= document.getElementById('mystring').value;
            var re = ^[ABC]{3}\\d{14}$;

            if(!re.test(mystring))
            {
                alert("mystringformat invalid");
            }
            else{
                alert("mystringformat valid");
            }       
        }); 
    });
```

Comment: Please include an *actual question* in your question.

Comment: what's your input string?

Comment: @user2132742 People won't answer quicker just because you tell them it's urgent.

Comment: Tried with \d its still not working

Comment: @user2132742 See my answer, it should work for you in case I got you right

Comment: @AvinashRaj Avinash, why it's not right approach?

Comment: Ahh, alright! This I can agree. He seems to be complete newby and not sure if he/she saw answers at all, as there were no comments at all.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a regex literal:

```
^[ABC]{3}\\d{14}$
```

In JavaScript, regex literals are surrounded in `/` characters.

Please read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: Can u please elaborate how to surround with / characters with an example

Comment: he means the regex should be `/^[ABC]{3}\\d{14}$/`;

Comment: @user2132742 Why don't you actually read an example of how to use a regex in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

**Regular expression:**

```
/^[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{14}$/
```

[Online example](http://regex101.com/r/tS2bE1/3)

Explanations:

- `[a-zA-Z]{3}` match a single character present in the list below, exactly 3 times

  - `a-z` a single character in the range between a and z (case sensitive)
  - `A-Z` a single character in the range between A and Z (case sensitive)
- `[0-9]{14}` match a single character present in the list below, exactly 14 times

  - `0-9` a single character in the range between 0 and 9

**Javascript:**

```
$("#mystring").keyup(function () {
    var $name = $(this).val();
    if (/^[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{14}/.test($name)) {
        alert("String is valid");
    } else {
        alert("String is invalid");
    }

});
```

[Online example](http://jsfiddle.net/m2Q73/)

Comment: This regex is significantly different than the apparent 'requirements'.

Comment: I does what the questioner expects.

Comment: It doesn't do what the OP says he wants. If you can indeed read minds, please teach me this ability.

Comment: By looking at the title and his array attempt to come up with proper *regex*.

Comment: Your regex definitely does not have "first three characters are alphabets [sic]"

Comment: Yes it does. Go to http://regex101.com/r/tS2bE1/1 and play with it

Comment: Alright.. Agree.. Editing

Comment: The first 3 characters of `12345678901234` aren't alphabetical.

Comment: `[\d+]` matches a digit or a `+`. *Pedantic note: `\d` matches other obscure symbols in Unicode.*

Answer (score 0):

regex definition is faulty, try:

```
var re = /^[ABC]{3}\d{14}$/;
```

Answer (score 0):

Strange that you want to check a **number** whose first three characters must be **alphabet**.

If you mean input string then you can try this

```
var re = /^[ABC]{3}[\d+]{14}/;
```